# 2sxc App Export/Import - Web Log app modified to a Book Reading Log

Tags: import, 2sxc

Environment(s) DNN 9.10.2 / 2sic_2SexyContent_14.07.04 Install / Oqtane 3.1.4

I've modified the 2sxc Blog module 4 to be a book reading log.

I've created 608 entries and wish to export/import to Oqtane 3.1.4 site.

I attempted the export from 2sxc without noting the module version and when importing the data I get the following error:

> Could not import the app / package: Sequence contains more than one matching element.

This is similar to https://github.com/2sic/2sxc/issues/460.

I've even installed 2sxc on another vanilla DNN 9.10.2 site and attempted the import on that (with the latest version of 2sxc 14.7.4 and get the same error.

I've seen in the Github issue noted above you could analyze the import process in your development environment? If so I'd be happy to send you the import zip file created from the App Export feature in 2sxc App Settings.

I have looked pretty deeply for any guidance on configuring the development environment for 2sxc and haven't been able to find anything. Also does anyone have good guidance on how to set up a development environment for the 2sxc modules? Would be great to include steps to set this up in Oqtane as I am moving all of my development energy moving forward to Oqtane module development - Oqtane is the next logical step for DNN Developers.

And also goes without saying that 2sxc is one of the best modules ever for DNN and offers a migration path away from DNN when you find that time coming. I've just gotten my Epiphany moment with Oqtane 3.1.4 realizing it is about at the same point DNN 2.1.2 was - a mature, extensible framework from which to build your .NET Core apps with.

Answer (score 0):

It's great to hear others are experimenting with Oqtane - awesome!

Your first step should be to check the insights log on the API call that does the import. It will probably show you exactly where it failed.

My guess is that it has to do with languages which are enabled / disabled differently in Dnn and Oqtane.